# Magento search box on Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, magento

I have a WP site on http://subdomain.example.com and a Magento site at http://example.com.
I was wondering what is the easiest way to add a Magento search box on the WP installation?

This is the WP search box code, but i dont know what parameter to modify since i have no idea how Magento works :(

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
    <div>
        <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s"><?php _x( 'Search for:', 'label' ); ?></label>
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s" />
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button' ); ?>" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a php script that gets the data from the magento site every time someone searchs . that would probably be the simplest way.

Comment: I dont need to get any data from Magento site :)
I need to "forward" the data entered in the search box on the WP site to the Magento search and then display results there.

Comment: So use the same form names and the action url of the magento site.

Answer (score 0):

Put the Magento catalogsearch url in the form action, and an input field with name attribute value "q" such as:

```
<form method="get" action="http://example.com/catalogsearch/result/">
    <input type="text" value="" name="q" />
```